# Visual Studio 2017 overwrote a file when I changed the filename, is there a way to revert that change?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I'm working on a project in visual studio, and I was switching between two instances of a file so I could showcase the differences between them. In order to switch between the files, I was being lazy and changing the filenames in file explorer outside of the IDE. It worked for a while, but unfortunately, this caused visual studio to overwrite one of the files with the other. I already checked the backup files, but my original file isn't there. Is there a way to undo this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

Ah, in case it isn't clear, the backup files I'm referring to are those located at MyDocuments\Visual Studio X\Backup Files\Project Name

Comment: Start using source control if you aren't already.

Comment: Yeah I really hope you are using source control, but this is not a solution, sometimes happens to lose the work of the day before doing commits and if you want avoid compulsive commits, I suggest to install LocalHistory: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lostalloy.LocalHistory-for-Visual-Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to revert what happened. In order to minimize the danger of losing your work because of that I suggest to check out [LocalHistory](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lostalloy.LocalHistory-for-Visual-Studio) and use some form of source control for long term development history. Also, VS Code has a **very** nice option for comparing files that's definitely a must if you do that kind of things often.